# (q/kdb+) Search column amounts

Tags: kdb

Can someone help me on the below?

```
nColss:1 3 4 4.5;
aa:([]amount:250000+500000*5?10;n1M:0.5*5?4;n3M:2+0.5*5?4;n4M:4+0.5*5?4;n4.5M:6+0.5*5?4);
aa:update nRng:{[l;n] (min l | l l bin n),(l l binr n & max l)}[nColss] each aa[`amount]%1000000 from aa;
aa:update nRng2:{`$("n",'string x),'"M"} each aa[`nRng] from aa;

amount  n1M n3M n4M n4.5M   nRng    nRng2
250000  1.5 2   4   7   1 1f    `n1M`n1M
2250000 0.5 2   5   6.5 1 3f    `n1M`n3M
4250000 1.5 2.5 5   6   4 4.5   `n4M`n4.5M
250000  1   3.5 4.5 7.5 1 1f    `n1M`n1M
1250000 1   2.5 4   7   1 3f    `n1M`n3M
```

How can I generate a column nValue containing for each line the value of the columns specified in the nRng2 column?

Something like this

```
nValue
1.5 1.5
0.5 2
5 6
1 1
1 2.5
```

I was trying something like

```
aa[aa[`nRng2]]
```

that generates

```
index   value
0   (1.5 0.5 1.5 1 1;1.5 0.5 1.5 1 1)
1   (1.5 0.5 1.5 1 1;2 2 2.5 3.5 2.5)
2   (4 5 5 4.5 4;7 6.5 6 7.5 7)
3   (1.5 0.5 1.5 1 1;1.5 0.5 1.5 1 1)
4   (1.5 0.5 1.5 1 1;2 2 2.5 3.5 2.5)
```

then I would need to take the diagonal of this matrix, but I am stuck at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get slightly different values in the `aa` table when I enter your example code, but something like this seems to work:

```
q)aa[`nValue]:{x x`nRng2} each aa
q)aa
amount  n1M n3M n4M n4.5M nRng    nRng2       nValue 
-----------------------------------------------------
4750000 0.5 2   4.5 6     4.5 4.5 n4.5M n4.5M 6   6  
1250000 0   3.5 5   6     1   3   n1M   n3M   0   3.5
3750000 0.5 2.5 5.5 7     3   4   n3M   n4M   2.5 5.5
250000  1   3   5   6.5   1   1   n1M   n1M   1   1  
750000  0   3   4.5 7     1   1   n1M   n1M   0   0
```

To give a quick explanation of what this is doing; by doing `each aa` we are essentially passing each record from the table into the lambda function as a dictionary (a table in kdb+ is simply a list of dictionaries). Within this we index into the record with `nRng2` to get the column names, and then index into the dictionary again using *those* column names. We then assign this using index notation to add a new column

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. Do you think it is possible to use nRng directly in the solution? Suppressing the creation of nRng2. Something like `trades[`nValue]:{x x`nRng2} each update nRng2:{`$("n",'string x),'"M"} each trades[`nRng] from trades;`

Comment: Using nRng directly: `update nValue:aa@'\`${"n",'x,'"M"} each string nRng from aa`